# error in code, unchecked conversion and unchecked method invocation error?

Tags: java, hashset

```
    List asList=Arrays.asList(text_arr);        
    Set<String> myset=new HashSet<String>(asList);
```

[unchecked] unchecked conversion
          Set myset1=new HashSet(asList1); 
 unchecked method invocation: constructor  in class HashSet is applied to given types
          Set myset1=new HashSet(asList1);

error found -Xlint:unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you are declaring a List as a generic collection, but without specifying the type. You should do just what you did with the HashSet:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>(); // or Arrays.asList(text_arr);
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

Hope it solves it.

Comment: List<String> list = new List<String>(); you cannot instantiate "new List<String>();" , you should provide its implementation, like ArrayList<>();